# CKEditor (ng2-ckeditor) often adds "&ZeroWidthSpace" (repeated 7 times) after the <img> tag when you paste an image

Tags: ng-ckeditor

CKEditor implemented in Angular (ng2-ckeditor) often adds "&ZeroWidthSpace" (repeated 7 times) after the \<img\> tag when you paste an image inside the editor area. By inspecting the Elements (hmtl) with Chrome, seraching inside the editor area immediately after copying an image, inside a paragraph of the CKEditor you will find two lines: firt line has the image tag (\<img src="data:image/ jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg ect....) and immediately below in the second line there is the string "&ZeroWidthSpace&ZeroWidthSpace&ZeroWidthSpace&ZeroWidthSpace&ZeroWidthSpace&ZeroWidthSpace&ZeroWidthSpace" (which subsequently, after saving and reloading the page, transforms into a string of 7 question marks "???????")

[inspetcing with Chrome after paste image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6QH7.png)